# Exclude modules from ng-build in Angular CLI... not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular5, tsconfig

I have an Angular CLI project with two apps in it. Both apps are the same, but one app includes all files in the build, the other needs to exclude a module.

Angular CLI version: 1.7.4
Angular version: 5.2.10

I added two apps into the angular-cli.json file, and each has a separate ts-config file.

```js
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app",   <---- first app
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "/wwwroot",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",       <----first TS config
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "admin",   <---- second app
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "/wwwroot",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.admin.json", <----- second ts config
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

The "admin" app will include all files.
However, the first app in the app array, "app" will exclude the admin module.

The tsconfig.app.json:

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "app/modules/admin/"    <----- note: I want this entire directory excluded from the build. 
  ]
}
```

I set up two "ng-build" scripts in the package.json file.

package.json build scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
    "build-app": "ng build -app app --prod",
    "build-admin": "ng build -app admin  --prod",
  },
```

To test this, I changed some text and styling in the admin module and ran the build locally. I noticed that the admin version of the app (which should build all files) works, but the "app" version of the app did NOT exclude the admin module.

Does anyone see anything missed/overlooked in the above snippets? 
Has anyone had similar problems and found a solution?

The angular-cli repo closed this issue but did not provide a fix. 
[see issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050)

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is reading this and looking for an answer:

TS is going to build any files it sees an 'import' statement for regardless of if it's in the 'exclude' property in tsconfig.json.

I had a import statement in my app.modules.ts file, and when I removed that... it was successfully excluded from the builds.

Comment: the exclude worked till Angular 4 I guess.,..But after migration to angular 6 , it says to include the module even though I mentioned it in exclude..Did you get any solution to exclude a ts file?

Comment: If you use LazyLoading, it will not work, because you should not import in app.modules.ts lazyLoaded modules

Answer (score 0):

On my application, I had an error because I had two modules including several modules/services... One was dedicated to the test (using HttpClientTestingModule instead of HttpClientModule).
Since it was in a testing/index.ts file it was automatically loaded at build and so was making everything failing.
Even if it was included only by the *.spec.ts files that needed it.
I tried to exclude it with the src/tsconfig.app.json and it worked:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "app/indalo-api/testing/*",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I deduce then that Angular 6 and above, will automatically load all .ts files except they are in the exclude, but they will be loaded if it is needed by one that is not excluded.

This makes sense.